# Change 'noends' name back to 'Algorithms' when using [noend]

Tags: algorithms

After I enabled the [noend] option, the names on the 'List of Algorithms' and algorithm pseudocode is changed to 'List of noends' and 'noend' respectively. how do I change it back? Thanks[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, oneside]{memoir}
\usepackage[noend]{algorithm, algpseudocode}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\listofalgorithms
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{HipHop} \label{alg:nb}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\ForAll{hip}
\State hop
\EndFor
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you say

```
\usepackage[option]{packageA, packageB}
```

then `option` is passed to ***both*** `packageA` ***and*** `packageB`, which is not, typically, what you want.

Use

```
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
```

to correct the problem.

[image: algorithms again!]

Comment: @kenniy There's a greyed-out check mark at the top left of my answer, where the votes are shown. Click it to accept this answer. ;)